# Mongodb, using data context when update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, meteor

I want to know is it possible that Use current data context when we update.

```
collection.update({_id: id},
  {$set:
    {'tmp.$.data': (function(){
      return this.a + this.b})()},
  {multi:true});
```

In the set operation, I tried to calculate something with IIFE function and 'this' keyword,
but there's nothing I can get as we expected, because that IIFE scope is placed outside of the update scope.
(a & b is an item in that object.)

That's what I want to do.

If we can control some data when we're doing update, I think it's really useful to manipulate collections.

Does anyone have idea about this?

Thanks in advance-

ps. I updated this question to js version.

Comment: What is `@a` and `@b`? If those are variables on `this` in the enclosing function, you can use the "fat arrow" - `do =>` instead of `do ->` - to bind the context of the function expression. Although it's probably simpler to do `data = @a + @b` outside of the `update` call, then just `$set: 'tmp.$.data': data`.

Comment: Thanks. I tested => keyword and printed this, but it seems it has nothing to useful information.

Comment: So it looks like that update call is inside a method. What are `a` and `b`? Are they fields in the documents themselves?

Comment: Yes. I think coffeeScript make the question confusing, so I updated it js version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I run into strangeness around `@` variables, I just make references outside of that closure. So from this:

```
collection.update (_id: id),
  ($set:
    'tmp.$.data': do ->
      return @a + @b),
  (multi:true)
```

To this:

```
a = @a
b = @b 
collection.update( 
  _id: id
  $set:
    'tmp.$.data': do ->
      return a + b
  multi:true
)
```

It seems like things can get goofed up when a function is expecting a function as an argument and get's something else. I'm not sure if that `do` in the `tmp.$.data` hash is really necessary either but I don't know meteor well enough to say yes or no.

Comment: actually @ keyword means this in the coffee script and do makes the function to be IIFE function.

Comment: @jwjin yes I realize that, but if the code on the other end is not expecting an IIFE it can goof things up. I've seen it happen, especially with fat arrows.